# Perform pure sql query using Fluent NHibernate in asp.net mvc4

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

how to perform a pure SQL join query using Fluent NHibernate and send the result to the view from controller in asp.net mvc4

Answer (score 0):

You may use the HQL query interface of nhibernate. The HQL language is designed to be independent of database provider.

All common joins can be expressed in HQL. Please read chapter 14 of the [nhibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql) (with examples at chapter 14.12).